# Find determinants of these matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question from my text:

[image]

For a) the determinant is 1 by triangular theorem (if it is an upper triangular, the determinant is just the product of the diagonals right?)

For b) we can use elementary row operations and change the first and third row which will negate the answer right? So the determinant is -1 right?

More importantly, why are we doing this? What is the point of finding determinants?

Comment: Your solutions are correct. Determnant are useful to determine if a linear map is bijective of not. They're also useful in computing the eigenvalues of a matrix, among a myriad of applications?

Comment: The determinant of a linear map is an important invariant of it, does not depend on chosen bases. From it, we can define the characteristic polynomial of the linear map, getting more invariants...